# How does one calculate the correct amplitude with R's fft()-function?

Tags: r, signal-processing, fft

In R, I am generating uncorrelated values in time domain with `rnorm()`. Then I apply `fft()` to these values, however, I am only getting a value of 0.88 instead of 1. Is there anything I am not aware of?

Here is a MWE:

```
# dt <- 0.01 # time stesp
nSteps <- 100000 # Number of time steps
# df <- 1/(nSteps*dt) # frequency resolution

# t <- 0:(nSteps-1)*dt # 
y <- rnorm(nSteps, mean=0, sd=1) # generate uncorrelated data. Should result in a white noise spectrum with sd=1
y_sq_sum <- sum(y^2)

# We ignore cutting to the Nyquist frequency.
# f <- 0:(nSteps-1)*df
fft_y <- abs(fft(y))/sqrt(length(y))
fft_y_sq_sum <- sum(fft_y^2)

print(paste("Check for Parseval's theorem: y_sq_sum = ", y_sq_sum, "; fft_y_sq_sum = ", fft_y_sq_sum, sep=""))

print(paste("Mean amplitude of my fft spectrum: ", mean(fft_y)))
print(paste("The above is typically around 0.88, why is it not 1?"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't belong on StackOverflow, it's more of a Cross-validated kind of thing.  But here's an answer anyway:

Parseval's theorem says that the mean of `fft_y^2` should be 1.  The square root function is a concave function, so Jensen's inequality says the mean of `sqrt(fft_y^2)` will be less than 1.  Since `fft_y` is positive in your definition, `fft_y = sqrt(fft_y^2)`.